# Custom forms in Drupal 8

Tags: forms, api, drupal, entity

I am struggling with some Drupal 8 form/entity type coding.
Basically here is a short summary of the task:
I have entity types which are from the eck module, so say three fields:
Name:
Email:
Phone:
So I have created a custom form using the FormBase class for users to fill in and that's fine but, I don't know how to save the post data to the entity.
If it was a node I would use the Node::create function but this is an entity so I need another way.
So I guess my task is:
 1. Get the ID of the entity I want to save too
 2. Find a way to save the form data to the entity

I am very new to Drupal 8 (just like most people I guess), I have tried Googling for info but I can't find anything that I understand, any help with this would be amazing, it should be a simple task I would have thought?

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't use the ECK module, so I don't know how it works exactly, I can only imagine. I build my entities by myself. 
But what I do know is that the FormBase class is the *wrong* (not wrong per se, but there's another class which handles exactly what you want) one to use to save entities. You're supposed to use the **ContentEntityForm** class for that.

Docs: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!ContentEntityForm.php/class/ContentEntityForm/8.2.x

The FormBase class is the generic form class, you use it basically for custom and simple stuff, where you only need the buildForm, validateForm and submitForm implementations (more or less).

Comment: Thanks for that Frank, yes I can see that now, cheers for the link also :)